# Azure Databricks won't access key vault permissions error from RBAC

Tags: azure, azure-databricks, azure-keyvault

I am trying to follow this tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/getting-started/connect-to-azure-storage

I have followed it to a tee but when I have got to Step 6: Connect to Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2 using python, I am getting an error trying to access the key vault.

My error is as such:

```
com.databricks.common.client.DatabricksServiceHttpClientException: PERMISSION_DENIED: Invalid permissions on the specified KeyVault https:X. Wrapped Message: Status code 403, "{"error":{"code":"Forbidden","message":"Caller is not authorized to perform action on resource.\r\nIf role assignments, deny assignments or role definitions were changed recently, please observe propagation time.\r\nCaller: name=AzureDatabricksnDecisionReason: 'DeniedWithNoValidRBAC' \r\nVault: KV;location=uksouth\r\n","innererror":{"code":"ForbiddenByRbac"}}}"
```

I assume this is some role so have added
Key Vault Administrator,
Key Vault Certificates Officer,
Key Vault Secrets User
to try and resolve the issue but still the same error. I'm new to this and can't figure out why this isn't working.

Any advise would be appreciated.

Comment: There are some existing issues with setting up Databricks to connect with a RBAC Key vault. Either use an access policy key vault or refer to this detailed article when using a RBAC keyvault https://medium.com/@scott.fountain/azure-databricks-and-azure-key-vault-access-via-rbac-dfa9817a5aba. The pitfall with this approach is that you will be giving full access to the entire key vault and not to a specific secret/key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The error usually occurs if you missed assigning proper RBAC role to **`AzureDatabricks`** service principal under your key vault.

When I tried the same in my environment without assigning role to `Azure Databricks` application, I got **same error** as below:

```py
service_credential = dbutils.secrets.get(scope="<scope>",key="<service-credential-key>")

spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.auth.type.<storage-account>.dfs.core.windows.net", "OAuth")
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.oauth.provider.type.<storage-account>.dfs.core.windows.net", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.oauth2.ClientCredsTokenProvider")
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.id.<storage-account>.dfs.core.windows.net", "<application-id>")
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.secret.<storage-account>.dfs.core.windows.net", service_credential)
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.endpoint.<storage-account>.dfs.core.windows.net", "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<directory-id>/oauth2/token")
```

**Response:**

```
com.databricks.common.client.DatabricksServiceHttpClientException: PERMISSION_DENIED: Invalid permissions on the specified KeyVault https://srikv151.vault.azure.net/. Wrapped Message: Status code 403, "{"error":{"code":"Forbidden","message":"Caller is not authorized to perform action on resource.\r\nIf role assignments, deny assignments or role definitions were changed recently, please observe propagation time.\r\nCaller: name=AzureDatabricks;appid=2ff814a6-3304-4ab8-85cb-xxxxxx;oid=fe597bb2-377c-44f1-8515-xxxxxxx;iss=https://sts.windows.net/72f988bf-86f1-41af-91ab-xxxxxxx/\r\nAction: 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/secrets/getSecret/action'\r\nResource: '/subscriptions/b83c1ed3-c5b6-44fb-b5ba-xxxxx/resourcegroups/v-sridevim/providers/microsoft.keyvault/vaults/srikv151/secrets/secret'\r\nAssignment: (not found)\r\nDenyAssignmentId: null\r\nDecisionReason: 'DeniedWithNoValidRBAC' \r\nVault: srikv151;location=eastus\r\n","innererror":{"code":"ForbiddenByRbac"}}}"
```

[image]

> To **resolve** the error, make sure to assign **Key Vault Administrator** role to **`AzureDatabricks`** service principal under your key vault.

You can use below CLI command for assigning role to **`AzureDatabricks`** service principal under your key vault:

```bash
az role assignment create --assignee-object-id <oid_from_error> --role "Key Vault Administrator" --scope "/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/{keyVaultName}"
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I checked the same in Portal, role assigned successfully to **`AzureDatabricks`** service principal under key vault:

[image]

You can now access Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2 account using python from **Azure Databricks** workspace.